# How to combine types from different libraries in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am using the the Rust libraries [swtweb](https://github.com/koute/stdweb) (to interface with JavaScript) and [serde-json](https://github.com/serde-rs/json) (to work with JSON). Both have a `Value` type to represent JavaScript objects that are very similar:

[swtweb's `Value`](https://github.com/koute/stdweb/blob/master/src/webcore/value.rs):

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum Value {
    Undefined,
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    Number(Number),
    Symbol(Symbol),
    String(String),
    Reference(Reference)
}
```

and [serde-json's `Value`](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/master/src/value/mod.rs):

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum Value {
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    Number(Number),
    String(String),
    Array(Vec<Value>),
    Object(Map<String, Value>),
}
```

What is an approach to transform instances of one type to another? Is it possible to derive a common trait without modifying the libraries?

Comment: Are you trying to *combine* the types or are you trying to *transform* them?

Comment: *a common trait* — have you tried this? What problems did you experience while attempting it? Have you read [the book chapter on traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html)?

Comment: I have values of both types and need to decide if I transform one type in another or create a third type and convert both of them. I am new to Rust and do not know all the options. Are traits the idiomatic option in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the doc of [`stdweb::Value`](https://docs.rs/stdweb/*/stdweb/enum.Value.html), it seems they have you covered!

It implements [`TryFrom<JsonValue>`](https://docs.rs/stdweb/*/stdweb/enum.Value.html#impl-TryFrom%3CJsonValue%3E), with `JsonValue` being an alias of `serde_json::Value`, so this lets you converts from `serde_json::Value` to `stdweb::Value`.

It implements [`Serialize`](https://docs.rs/stdweb/*/stdweb/enum.Value.html?search=#impl-Serialize), and [`serde_json::to_value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.to_value.html) lets you convert any type that implements `Serialize` to a `serde_json::Value`

So this should work:

```
let json_value: serde_json::Value = json!("my value");
println!("{:#?}", json_value);

let stdweb_value: stdweb::Value = stdweb::Value::try_from(json_value).unwrap();
println!("{:#?}", stdweb_value);

let json_value_again: serde_json::Value = serde_json::to_value(stdweb_value).unwrap();
println!("{:#?}", json_value_again);
```